# Git - list lines of code with changes from an author in the current branch

Tags: git

Is there a way to list the lines of code with changes from a specific author?
I just want that for the files in the current branch.

E.g. sth. like this:

- src/fileA.c:12
- src/fileA.c:34
- src/subFolder/fileB.c:56

As an alternative, the files in the current branch, that a specific author changed, would also help.

Thanks!

Comment: Files are not in *branches* but rather in *commits*. (Any given commit is then contained in zero or more branches, but you need to think about this in terms of commits, not branches.) You're probably looking for `git blame` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first part (line changes by an author) of your question has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32321085/3715736)

and the second part (all files changed by an author) has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6349405/3715736)